# Minimax algorithm inaccurate result

Tags: java, algorithm, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I'm trying to implement minimax with alpha beta pruning for a checkers game. When the game starts, the first 2 or 3 movements are okay with the AI but then I start getting inaccurate best positions, such as 7,7 which is the end of the board.

Here is my code, maybe I'm doing something very stupid here.

```
 public int minimax(int depth, int player, int alpha, int beta) {
    int bestScore;
    if(player == 1) 
        bestScore = -1;
    else 
        bestScore = 1;

    List<Position> positionsAvailable = getAvailableStates();
    if(seCount < level || Checkers.limit == 6) {
        if (computerHasWon()) {
            seCount++;
            return +1; // Static evaluation result for the AI winning   
        }
        if (humanHasWon()) {
            seCount++;
            return -1; // Static evaluation result for the AI losing
        }
        if (positionsAvailable.isEmpty()) {
            seCount++;
            return 0; // Static evaluation result for a draw
        }
   }
   else 
        return 0;
    // because the game tree is only 9 levels deep, we store the results in a list
    // do not do this with more complex problems!
    //List<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < positionsAvailable.size(); i++) {
        // determine all board positions that aren't occupied
        Position pos = positionsAvailable.get(i);  
        deCount++;
        if (player == 1) { //agent's turn: get the highest result returned by minimax
            // place a piece at the first available position
            placePiece(pos, 1);
            // get the minimax evaluation result for making the previous move
            int currentScore = minimax(depth - 1, 2, alpha, beta); // Increase 
            if(currentScore > bestScore) bestScore = currentScore;
            alpha = Math.max(currentScore, alpha);
            // store a mapping of complete evaluations (at depth 0) and their scores
            if (depth == 0) 
                successorEvaluations.add(new PositionsAndScores(currentScore, pos));
        } else if (player == 2) {//Human's turn - get the lowest result returned by minimax
            //bestScoreMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            placePiece(pos, 2);
            int currentScore = minimax(depth + 1, 1, alpha, beta);
            if(currentScore < bestScore) bestScore = currentScore;
            beta = Math.min(currentScore, beta);
        }
        board[pos.x][pos.y] = 0; //Reset this pos

        if(alpha>=beta) {
            pCount++;
            break;
        }
    }
    return bestScore;        
}
```

Comment: In your `else if (player == 2) {...}`, shouldn't you recursively call the function with `depth - 1`? Also, `alpha = max(bestscore, alpha)` and `beta = min(beta, bestscore)`

Comment: @RafiduzzamanSonnet That's what I'm confused about, if I set depth -1 for both player 1 and 2 then AI player makes random movements to corners of the board. What do you think?

Comment: I think someone experienced should answer your question :P

Comment: what does it mean, an inaccurate position, "7,7". Are those coordinates? And if so, why is it inaccurate?